# Vue - How to render a table with two data per tr

Tags: css, vue.js, css-tables

As attachment, How I use v-for or v-repeat or something else to do this? 
thanks for your help.

[How to render a table with two data per tr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gep1r.png)

JSON Data Format:
[
  'a',
  'b',
  'c'
]

Comment: This is more like a CSS problem, not related to vue.js directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a CSS problem, you just render the table normally. The key CSS is:

```
tr {
  float: left;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  clear: left;
}
```

See this example: http://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/peKeNw?editors=0110

Comment: Thank you , u are my hero : )